# The use of Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in Spectroscopy

Tags: solid-state-physics, computational-physics, laser, spectroscopy

Greetings there fellow users.

I am to prepare and give a seminar on  Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in the subject of Laser Spectroscopy (aka solid state spectroscopy).
Now i am quite comfortable in the topic, and i plan to do a Jupyter Notebook with toy data sets as experiments, but, i would like to know if anyone knows the role of PCA in Spectroscopy in general? I mean it is all fun and everything to get a large cancer data set online and do PCA on it but i would like to keep more in the Physics side of things.
Thus far the only thing google has helped me with is that it is used in noise reduction. But that does not tell me much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. You talk about being comfortable in PCA w.r.t. laser spectroscopy, but your question seems to indicate lack of knowledge in regards to PCA overall.

Comment: @kyle No i actually specialize in computational physics. I do SVD, POD and Quantum Gases on the daily. This is my first class in Spectroscopy and i just do not understand that well how to apply PCA to concepts. As some guy answered below, i actually took a look at NIR spectroscopy and even found a free Database of NIR analysis on pharmaceuticals. https://openmv.net/info/tablet-spectra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at gas sensing, Raman Spectroscopy, or NIR spectroscopy as applications? NIR spectroscopy the signals can be broader and overlapping.

In general I think PCA is one tool in the tool box and in general applicable for complex signatures and it helps to have orthogonal signals.  Knowing other parameters such as temperature, or humidity can be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I managed to find experimental data on NIR spectroscopy that i can actually do PCA on.  https://openmv.net/info/tablet-spectra